# Add new fields in windows explorer, using C#

Tags: c#, windows-explorer

Is there any way of adding extra fields to the details view of windows explorer? Similar to the 'dimensions' field of images, or the 'SVN Status' field that TortoiseSVN adds?

I've got a program that lists information about each file in a folder, I'm just thinking it would be so much easier to use if I could do this.

Comment: That would make your program a **permanent extension** to the system - is that what you want?

Comment: Well, that depends; would uninstalling the program remove them again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Property System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728898(VS.85).aspx) lets you do that in Vista and later. Windows XP did the same thing using [Column shell extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776831(VS.85).aspx).